# How can I change actionbar actions (items) on selected navigationdrawer item?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

I want to change the actions when I select an item from the NavigationDrawer. Is that possible and what's the right way to do that? I am using an Activity that implements the NavigationDrawerFragment.

[image: navigation/actions]

Thank you

Comment: When you select the special item in the navigation drawer you could set a flag and call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`. Your `onCreateOptionsMenu()` callback would need to check that flag to inflate the proper menu layout.

Comment: Thank you very much :) that's what I was looking for. You can post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use fragments and each fragment should call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in the `onCreateView()` and `onResume()` method of that fragment. You can do this if you are using ActionBarSherlock,

```
getSherlockActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

and, then, in each of your fragments build the menu with

```
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

}
```

this allows you to have different actions in the ActionBar for each fragment.

If you just want to change your actions from the same fragment or activity, then you should put the `invalidateOptionsMenu()` call in the action that was pressed. This will cause the `onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu)` to be recalled and that will rebuild your actions for you according to what code you have in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`.

Hope this helps. If anything is unclear, please don't hesitate to ask.